# How to convert std::string to LPVOID

Tags: stdstring

I need convert std::string to LPVOID for create PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER.

Already i have tested some casting but my PE Header isn't right.

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open("C:/testDLL.enc");
std::string data;
file >> data;
file.close();;

std::string decrypted = decrypt(data);

LPVOID lpData = static_cast<LPVOID>(&decrypted[0]);

//LPVOID lpData = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>((char*)decrypted.c_str());
//LPVOID lpData = (char*)decrypted.c_str();

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpData;
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: such basic or better fundamental questions are subject to be duplicates, e.g. did you check https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18069038

Comment: So you got your pointer. What is your question? It is unclear what problem you are having.

Comment: My PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER is broken. when i take lpData with ReadFile its working good

Comment: Then you have a bug in your code. There is nothing special about `PVOID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string decryptempty(string data)
{
    // I dont know your decrypt & encrypt functions..

    return string(data);
}
int main() {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("C://testDLL.dll",ios::binary); 
    std::string data;
    file >> data;
    file.close();

    string decryptedstr = decryptempty(data);
    LPVOID ptr = &decryptedstr[0];
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDos = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(ptr);

    printf("e_magic : %02x\n", pDos->e_magic);
    printf("string buffer : %p\n", ptr);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

> output : e_magic : 5a4d string buffer : 00B53A50

e_magic correct.

Comment: Actually i dont need this, when i write my decoded data to file and take it back its dangerous for me also i encrypting file for security. thanks.